# how to get data that generated by AJAX from a website in android app

Tags: android, ajax, jsoup

---

i wanna extract data from a website in my android app.i used jsoup and httpget and InputStreamReader for this but The problem is that the text i want is shown in the browser and hidden when I got though code.it means that  "show page source" option of browser doesn't display that text.i think that text likely  generate by ajax.can anyone help me how to get that text?

---

thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find out which requests your browser makes in the background using a network analysis tool. For inspecting HTTP traffic, there is a broad selection of tools available. I recommend a browser extension like [HttpFox](https://addons.mozilla.org/de/firefox/addon/httpfox/) or a standalone tool like [Fiddler 2](http://www.telerik.com/fiddler). The procedure is pretty simple and always the same: Browse to the site and make sure the desired resource was loaded. Then, inspect the recorded traffic. Either, an obvious URL or mime type will point you to the right resource, or you'll find the resource by inspecting the responses.
This procedure works in most cases. It is only rarely needed to actually run or inspect scripts in the page.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that ajax / ASP pages are generated dynamically using triggered by scripting run on the browser side that generate the code.   JSoup just makes HTTP requests to get the HTML but does not execute the java scripts needed by many ajax sites to generate the full page.   The 'view page source' in the browser will show all the source as generated dynamically by scripts.

In order to handle this, you will need to upgrade to a headless browser to read these sites.  This can be done by a few different tools in Java:
[HtmlUnit](http://htmlunit.sourceforge.net/)
[Selenium](http://docs.seleniumhq.org/)

Comment: thanks @Andrew Phillips.one said htmlunit doesn't work in android.is it true?by the way i haven't checked it yet.

Comment: It doesn't look like it.   HTMLUnit depends on you AWT, swing, etc that just are not available on Android.  Might be better off sending the request to a server running HTMLUnit or Selenium to return the data.  This can be done using a custom tomcat app and restful client.   But this might be more complicated than you wanted to get into, but honestly might be the best option.   Another option is to load the page in a webview injecting java script to perform actions.  See this post: [Headless Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17399055/android-web-scraping-with-a-headless-browser)