# finding json or xml data from a webpage to android app

Tags: android, xml, json

I am trying to fetch seat availability from this ticket booking site to my android app  ,but i cant find it from this website. Can anyone tell me how to get those info from a website like this..Where can i find the json or xml data of the seat availability or other info. Also if its using other protocol can you tell me which one is it?

http://tinyurl.com/3zetk5d/

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can't directly fetch data from a webpage. The developers of the webpage should provide APIs (web endpoints) which give you the relevant data in a particular format.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [jsoup](http://jsoup.org/) to scrape data from webpages. Beware of the legal aspect ;)

Take a look at this: [Android Web Scraping with a Headless Browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17399055/android-web-scraping-with-a-headless-browser)